# STM32 H7 - Outputs wrong I2S BCLK (1.027 Mhz pulses, expected 1.024)?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, stm32h

The STM32 seems to be a nightmare... Just such weird issues constantly. Anyways, I'm trying to output Master I2S (with BCLK, no MCLK) at 16 kHz, but for some reason am getting a 1.027 MHz clock causing audio artifacts. Input clock is PLL2 or PLL3, doesn't make a difference at 2.048 MHz or 20.48 MHz, doesn't make a difference...

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Again, same or different STM32H7 and if same then which is it again? And the rest of the clock settings?

Comment: Show us your PLL configuration.

Comment: @Justme, one is an ESP32 producing the correct clock and the problem is with the STM32... 

brhans, edited to include the clocks

Answer (score 0):

So this ended up being the need to switch to the HSE clock on the STlink that's part of the nucleo board. The HSE is more accurate and combined with an updated clock tree, did the trick.

Comment: But it already is on HSE based on the screenshot?

Comment: Yes and no... It needs to be changed in the STLink firmware utility to HSE, 25/3 Mhz.